# get current image from picture html tag

Tags: html, jquery, css, image, tags

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="/images/xxxxxxxxxx.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/yyyyyyyyyy.jpg">
    <img src="/images/zzzzzzzzzz.jpg">
</picture>
```

I need to assign the active image or another tag. How can I get it with jquery or CSS?

Comment: What exactly is an "active image"?

Comment: The image that is displayed according to the resolution

Comment: Follow up to Dennis's question. How are you planning to get the src? Button click? Console log?

Comment: when  the resolution is change. No buttons

Comment: What you have should work? The code you provided will automatically use the image based on the screens width. 

Default picture would be zzzzzzz.jpg

After screen is at least 768px it will use yyyyy.jpg

Then once the screen is at least 992px wide it will use xxxx.jpg

Is it not working?

Comment: Yes, work! I need to get the src of the image being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments ,i understand what you want .

try this:

```
$('picture').on('change',function(){
    console.log($('picture > img').attr('src')); //will return image
})
```

i hope it was useful

Comment: Suggestions to try something belong in comments.

Comment: Always get the default image... (img tag)